# MVC post submit value as part of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For pages with multiple submit buttons, I use the following pattern:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ModelId{ get; set; }
    public string SubmitValue {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="First">First</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Second">Second</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, string submit)
{
    switch(submit)...
}
```

Is it possible to set SubmitValue on the model instead of having the extra string parameter so that I can do

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    switch(model.SubmitValue)...
}
```

Preferably without Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Change the name value of your button tags to match your property `SubmitValue`.

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitValue" value="First">First</button>
<button type="submit" name="SubmitValue" value="Second">Second</button>
```